# Show message within 30 days of a Termination date NetSuite workflow

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I am attempting to create a workflow where **Before User Edit**s, the user will get a message if the Termination date is within 30 days from today. Since the Show Message action only performs on the client side, I was reading that I have to use Javascript functions instead of SQL functions. However, I can't for the life of me figure this out. This is a screenshot of what I am using to test:

[Formula Condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STOvt.png)

If there is anything else you would like to know please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try by setting trigger on "Before Field Edit"

Comment: Just tried it, but it didn't do anything. Essentially, I would want to keep it as Before User Edit.